# lsapp.test on browser not giving the index page instead localhost/lsapp/public/ gives the home page

Tags: laravel, apache, routes

I have set up the environment for virtual hosts using Apache. I am facing three problems.

1) I am unable to go to the index page by using lsapp.test on my browser (I have set lsapp.test for 127.0.0.1 and also the same for the localhost. It gives a `404` error.

2) If I go to localhost/lsapp on the browser the whole directory is visible (I assume which means my virtual host is not working as it should be)

3) On the browser, `http://localhost/lsapp/public/` leads me to my root.
`Web.php` is as follows:

```
 Route::get ('/', function() {
      return 'Hello World';
 });
```

Gives me Hello world on the browser as expected. BUT the problem is if I try to navigate to my about page through

```
 Route::get ('/about', function() {
     return 'about';
 });
```

It gives `404` error. I have been breaking my head for the past 2 days. This could be a simple problem but so far I haven't figured out a solution.

I have checked the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file in Apache folder and hosts file in System32>drivers>etc if I have done the right settings and it looks fine.

This question does not require codes

`lsapp.test` on the browser must go to the home page. Also, I must be able to browse other pages.

Comment: the index page is in `return view('welcome');` , what do you mean with `virtual host`?

Comment: I am trying to use Apache Virtual host service

Answer (score -1):

Your document root should be `lsapp/public/` and `index.php` must catch all request.

Apache Vhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/your-project/public
```

See:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/deployment

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
        ServerName localhost
        </VirtualHost>

       
The document root is already lsapp/public and this is the actual lines in my vhost

        <VirtualHost *:80>
         DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"
         ServerName lsapp.test
        </VirtualHost>